# How do I select two columns containing different data from the same field

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to select two different data descriptions from the same field. The data is differentiated by the Type and ID columns in the same table. Below is the query I am trying but I am getting duplicate data results. Attached are screenshots of the two tables and the query results[image: Table and Results].

```
SELECT SEX,[ADDRESS],CITY,SOC_SEC_NUM,ZIP,ect...

CASE WHEN CD.[TYPE] = 'COUNTY'
THEN CD.[DESC] 
END AS COUNTY,

--CASE WHEN CDTBL1.[TYPE] = 'ETH'
--THEN CDTBL1.[DESC] 
--END AS ETH

CDTBL1.[DESC] AS ETH
--CD.[DESC] AS COUNTY

--INTO #TMP
FROM CDCLIENT
INNER JOIN CDTBL1
ON CDCLIENT.ETH_ID = CDTBL1.ID
INNER JOIN CDTBL1 CD
ON CAST(CDCLIENT.RES_COUNTY_ID AS VARCHAR) = CD.ID

WHERE CDTBL1.[TYPE] = 'ETH'
--AND CD.[DESC] IS NOT NULL
--OR 
--CD.[TYPE] = 'COUNTY'
ORDER BY LAST_NAME ASC

--SELECT * FROM #TMP
--WHERE COUNTY IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you have duplicate ID's. I would add some another condition to your join for the TYPE.

```
SELECT SEX,[ADDRESS],CITY,SOC_SEC_NUM,ZIP,ect...

CASE WHEN CD.[TYPE] = 'COUNTY'
THEN CD.[DESC] 
END AS COUNTY,

--CASE WHEN CDTBL1.[TYPE] = 'ETH'
--THEN CDTBL1.[DESC] 
--END AS ETH

CDTBL1.[DESC] AS ETH
--CD.[DESC] AS COUNTY

--INTO #TMP
FROM CDCLIENT
INNER JOIN CDTBL1 
ON CDCLIENT.ETH_ID = CDTBL1.ID AND CDTBL1.TYPE = 'ETH'
INNER JOIN CDTBL1 CD
ON CAST(CDCLIENT.RES_COUNTY_ID AS VARCHAR) = CD.ID AND CD.TYPE = 'COUNTY'

WHERE CDTBL1.[TYPE] = 'ETH'
--AND CD.[DESC] IS NOT NULL
--OR 
--CD.[TYPE] = 'COUNTY'
ORDER BY LAST_NAME ASC

--SELECT * FROM #TMP
--WHERE COUNTY IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to SQLChao response, you also can replace your initial `SELECT` by `SELECT DISTINCT`, with this option you remove duplicated results.